# Looking for sortable table in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am looking for Sortable Table in angular4, is there any out of box available? I saw examples for ng2table and Bootstrap table integrated into Angular4 component with custom sort implementation. I would like to go for Bootstrap table with custom sort method. can anyone suggest which is better?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For sortable tables, inline editable tables, and pretty much every other action you can do with a table you're going to want to go with [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/). The [out of the box table sorting](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/sort) is lightweight (only includes the modules you need in a good ol' Angular fashion) and their entire repo tends to be clean and well maintained

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. It seems Bootstrap is better solution for me.